# class name in method along with variable

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am reading about design patterns in PHP and I keep seeing the following syntax, for example

```
abstract class AbstractObserver {
    abstract function update(AbstractSubject $subject_in);
}
```

or

```
class PatternObserver extends AbstractObserver {
    public function __construct() {
    }
    public function update(AbstractSubject $subject) {   
    }
}
```

(code is part of [this](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/php) example)

where "AbstractSubject" is another abstract class.

I am used to defining methods like `methodName($var)`, not including a class name in there, like `methodName(className $var)`.

So, what actually the class name does in a method ? My best guess is that it passes something like a reference in that class? Can you explain to me what it actually does?

Thanks

Comment: It's called [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration), and it defines the datatype that the argument must be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Type Hinting](https://www.sitepoint.com/type-hinting-in-php/), since php 7 you can use [scalar types](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) to type hint parameters. ([Some more](https://www.sitepoint.com/type-hinting-in-php/))