# pass an object to another object constructor in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am reading about design patterns in PHP and I keep seeing the following syntax, for example

`$newClass = new myClass(new myOtherClass());`

I guess that this passes some kind of a `myOtherClass` reference inside `myClass`, so here

```
class myClass{

    private $myOtherClass;

    public function __construct(myOtherClass $myOtherClass) {
        $this->myOtherClass= $myOtherClass;
    }

    public function myClassMethod($var) {
        $this->myOtherClass->methodOfMyOtherClass($var);
    }
}
```

the construct refers to `myOtherClass` and
I can use the `methodOfMyOtherClass` of `myOtherClass` from the `myClass` `myClassMethod`, like so `$newClass->myClassMethod('a value here');`

My questions are :

What is the name of that practice?

Did I got the concept right?

Where can I read more about it?

(first time I saw this syntax is [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-patterns-the-adapter-pattern--cms-22262), this is where I also based my code for this question)

Comment: Its called [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Comment: Dependency Injection

Comment: Specifying the type of object that is required in the arguments list is called "type hinting", as we answered you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288512/class-name-in-method-along-with-variable)

Comment: Passing arguments to a constructor so that they can be used in later calls to methods of that class is called "dependency injection"

Comment: @DarenChandisingh is right, it's called dependency injection. Symfony framework have a very powerfull dependency injection if you want to take a look ;)

Comment: what will good practice `inheritance` or `dependency injection` because in inheritance we can easily extend class instead of init new object every time calling class like using constructor method

Comment: Extension isn't a substitute for dependency injection; they're two different things

Comment: And (as a general rule) I'd recommend composition over inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the name of that practice?
Typically this is called `Dependency Injection`. `myClass` required `myOtherClass` in order to properly execute it's methods, so `myOtherClass` is a dependency of `myClass`. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Did I got the concept right?
It looks like you have the concept right. At least based on your sample, you are using it correctly.

Where can I read more about it?
If you want to read more about Dependency Injection only, I recommend [this](https://12factor.net/dependencies). In general, the principles taught by the 12 Factor App are very good and are worth reading about. [12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/).

Some good books worth reading along these lines:
[Clean Code](http://a.co/967Ol45)
[Patterns for Enterprise Architecture](http://a.co/a1mssS3)

Comment: and [this article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), too.